# Is it possible to have a timestamp (date and time) field in a modal?

Tags: slack-api

Reading through the docs, I see a [date picker](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#datepicker) and [time picker](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#timepicker) field separately but not just one timestamp field that includes both. Is there any way to accomplish this same idea outside the box?

Answer (score 0):

What about datetimepicker? Check it out here: https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see datetimepicker as an option under input when I go to the block kit builder? Is this new? Curious if my workspace has to upgrade for me to see it or something.